# I need to make button to go to another page workable if it's written in php code(with echo)

Tags: php, html

i need to make the html that is written in php(via echo) workable

```
<?php
echo   
"
   <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
             <div onclick='location.href'='car_details.php';' >
                 ...
             </div>
        </body>
    </html>
"
?>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using an anchor tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quotes are wrong. It should be

```
<div onclick='location.href=\"car_details.php\"' >
```

You have to escape the double quotes because otherwise they would end the string started with `echo "`.

Comment: that worked thanks, didn't know about \"... \"